# Laptop requirements with kinect xbox1

Tags: kinect

I am using kinect xbox1 for window camera, for computing skeleton data and rgb data.I am retrieving 30 frames per second. Also calculating joint values of human body and then calculate angle between joints. I want that my laptop/system compute faster values of joints and angle. And store into  directory.But recently i am using my laptop which compute the joint values and angle very slowly. 
Specification of my laptop are:
500GB Hard
600GB RAM
1.7GHZ processor
Kindly tell me which system i am used to calculate faster calculation. I want really fast system/laptop to calculate very fast calculations. Anyone have idea please tell me.
And also tell me the complete specifications of system. I want to use latest fastest technology or any machine which resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer must have the following minimum capabilities:

- 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64) processors
- **Dual-core**, **2.66-GHz** or faster processor
- USB 2.0 bus dedicated to the Kinect
- 2 GB of RAM
- Graphics card that supports DirectX 9.0c
  Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855359.aspx)

Anyway I suggest you: 
A Desktop PC 
with a Processor with **3Ghz** (More are usually better) **multi-core** processor
with a **GPU** compatible with **DirectX 11** and C++ AMP